# Quiero agregar todos los elementos de un ListBox a una List<int> (ERROR La conversión especificada no es válida)

Tags: c#, arraylist, sql-server-2008, listbox

Cargo todos los datos en un `ListBox`, quiero tomar todos esos datos agregados y mandarlos a una `List<int>`, obviamente tengo todo controlado que los datos que se cargan al `listbox` sean enteros, pero al hacer el `foreach` para ir pasando los enteros a la lista me da error.
Un ejemplo de lo que hago sería así:

```
List<int> listaTel = new List<int>();

foreach (int item in lstTelefonos.Items)
{
      listaTel.Add(item);
}
```

después eso para mandar a la base de dato me da error que aclaré en el titulo
cual puede ser mi erorr?

Comment: y como lo mandas a la base de datos? o sea, donde da ese error?

Comment: No termino de entender tu pregunta...el error es en el foreach que nos muestras? o al "mandar a la base de datos"?

Comment: Mandar a la base de datos quise decir cuando apretas el botón  agregar, que lo guarda en la BD

Answer (score 0):

Intenta este código, si funciona te explico por que.

```
List<int> myList=new List<int>();
foreach (string myInt in lstValues.Items)
{
    myList.Add(Int32.Parse(myInt));
}
MessageBox.Show("working");
```

Comment: Corregido* favor de intentar ya lo probé y funciona

Comment: Lo probé y me sale eso ahora: 
No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' al tipo 'System.String'.